# Having trouble getting my DataGridView to sort

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGridView which is bound to a `List<MyType>`

Automatic sorting didn't work, so I tried to tackle it programatically.

The Sort method takes a non-generic IComparer which I created and used, but I get the error:

> DataGridView control is data-bound. The control cannot use the
>   comparer to perform the sort operation.

Any ideas how I can get this to sort?

Edit: More research shows that you should be sorting the source in a scenario where it's bound. I am using a `BindingSource` but it has no Sort() method.

Comment: take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95scxcdy%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: The DataSource for your BindingSource should be your List<>Object and You should use LINQ to filter your list object.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by use LINQ? Do you mean create a new BindingSource when sorting and change the linq query as appropriate?

Comment: I guess you do, cos it works! Cheers, can you post that as an anwer?

Answer (score 0):

There's a method called Sort on the dataGridView..Use the method as like:

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Hope this helps:)